# Why is iPhone not available in Hardware -> Device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

On my simulator under `Hardware -> Device` I only see iPhone Retina but not iPhone alone.

Is there a reason for this? am I missing iPhone?

[image]

Comment: Apple's way of saying it's obsolete.

Comment: What is your project set-up to support?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your project's Deployment Target is iOS 7.0 or later then that is why you don't see non-retina iPhone choices.

- iOS 7 doesn't run on any non-retina iPhones or iPod Touches
- iOS 7 does run on the iPad 2 and the non-retina iPad minis, which is why you do see the iPad option

Comment: really? iOS 7 doesn't run on non-retina devices? if a device is `iPhone 4S (iOS 7.0.6)` does that then mean that it is retina?

Comment: Every iPhone since the iPhone 4 is retina.